# Is there an ArcGIS to PostGIS function cross-reference table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, geoprocessing

I was looking back at the presentation called "[PostGIS Tips for Power Users](http://s3.opengeo.org/postgis-power.pdf)" by Paul Ramsey and got to thinking... Has anyone ever seen an ArcGIS Geoprocessing Tool to PostGIS function cross-reference table?  In particular, pages 21-27.  For ArcGIS users attempting to transition to PostGIS, I would think this could be very helpful.

I know of the following resources, but not aware of anything to help users learn the right terminology in PostGIS from what they already know in ArcGIS.

- [PostGIS 2.0 Cheatsheet](http://www.postgis.us/downloads/postgis20_cheatsheet.html)
- [PostGIS Manual](http://postgis.net/docs/)

For example, I was thinking something like this:
[image]

Comment: It might be a good idea, but we have to remember that is many cases, there isn't a 1:1 correspondence between the GP Tools and PostGIS Functions. For example, in your image, The function that you have used for Dissolve, doesn't work in all cases. sometimes you need to give a tolerence for it to work quickly.

Comment: To address @DevdattaTengshe comment, maybe you could add a Comment column at the end to help qualify any comparisons being made.

Comment: Yeah, I certainly agree that there may not be a 1:1 correlation, but I was just thinking of a way to point people in the right direction.